# Spark dataframe transverse of columns

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have ticket transaction systems. Sample dataframe looks like below. Every day will have 2 records with how many ticket & value of tickets were booked through channel(only 2 channel is possible. Passenger,Agent)

```
date,channel,ticket_qty,ticket_amount 
20011231,passenger,500,2500
20011231,agent,100,1100 
20020101,passenger,450,2000
20020101,agent,120,1500
```

I want to make it to single record per date& removing channel. Like below

```
date,passenger_ticket_qty,passenger_ticket_amount,agent_ticket_qty,agent_ticket_amount
20011231,500,2500,100,1100
20020101,450,2000,120,1500
```

I have acheived it in below way.

```
val pas_df= spark.read.csv(filepath).option("header","true")
             .filter($"channel" === "passenger")

val agent_df= spark.read.csv(filepath).option("header","true")
             .filter($"channel" === "agent")

val df = pas_df.as("pdf").join(agent_df.as("adf"), $"adf.date" === $"pdf.date")
       .select($"pdf.date" as date,
               $"pdf.ticket_qty" as passenger_ticket_qty,
               $"pdf.ticket_amount" as passenger_ticket_amount,
               $"adf.ticket_qty" agent_ticket_qty,
               $"adf.ticket_amount" as agent_ticket_amount)
```

This is working perfect way.But it takes around 3 hrs since the file 40yrs of records.

Is there a better way to get this done without join?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful-

### Load the data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |date,channel,ticket_qty,ticket_amount
        |20011231,passenger,500,2500
        |20011231,agent,100,1100
        |20020101,passenger,450,2000
        |20020101,agent,120,1500
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
//      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +--------+---------+----------+-------------+
      * |date    |channel  |ticket_qty|ticket_amount|
      * +--------+---------+----------+-------------+
      * |20011231|passenger|500       |2500         |
      * |20011231|agent    |100       |1100         |
      * |20020101|passenger|450       |2000         |
      * |20020101|agent    |120       |1500         |
      * +--------+---------+----------+-------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- date: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- channel: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- ticket_qty: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- ticket_amount: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Use `pivot` and `first`

```scala
  df.groupBy("date")
      .pivot("channel")
      .agg(
        first("ticket_qty").as("ticket_qty"),
        first("ticket_amount").as("ticket_amount")
      ).show(false)

    /**
      * +--------+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
      * |date    |agent_ticket_qty|agent_ticket_amount|passenger_ticket_qty|passenger_ticket_amount|
      * +--------+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
      * |20011231|100             |1100               |500                 |2500                   |
      * |20020101|120             |1500               |450                 |2000                   |
      * +--------+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
      */
```